# DIY Tomcat, where is the webapp folder on the local git repo

Tags: openshift

following OpenShift tutorials, creating  a tomcat application and clone it, the local repository will contain a pom.xml, webapp folder.
What's the equivalent on a diy application that contain a diy and misc folders

Thank's in advance, any help is appreciated cause I'm really stuck here !?

**Update**

Well I've install a Tomcat 8 DIY application following this tutorial [here](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-8-on-openshift/) everything works fine, I can see the Tomcat page in the browser, **the problem is how to deploy a .war file.**

For a **Tomcat 6/7  application** on OpenShift, the local git repository have this structure:

```
____Tomcat7/6 
    |_________ webapp
    |_________ src
    |_________ pom.xml
```

But for a Tomcat 8 DYI application I have this structure

```
________Tomcat8/diy
        |__________ Diy
        |__________ misc
        |__________ readme
```

**So Where to deploy my .war files, cause there is no webapp folder?**

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do, show the directory layout of your current project, and describe exactly which step doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Really thank's for the reply, I ve been stuck here, I m new to openShift, I edit my question, hope that's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question suggests that you are mixing up at least 5 different, completely independent & orthogonal tools and concepts:

- **Git** is a version control system ("push", "local repo")
- **Maven** is a build tool ("pom.xml")
- **Apache Tomcat** is a servlet container ("Tomcat 6/7/8")
- **rhc** is some client tool provided by yet another cloud computing platform ("OpenShift")
- Your code is the stuff that you have written, it's completely under your responsibility.

Before you start doing anything, please make sure that you have at least some basic understanding of what each of these tools does. Then ask yourself whether you really need **Tomcat 8** instead of **Tomcat 7**, and whether a 2 year blog post about the compilation of **Tomcat 8** within an **OpenShift** gear is the best source. All these deployment details can change pretty quickly, if it worked two years ago, it's not guaranteed that it would work now.

I've never worked with OpenShift, but as far as I understand, the basic idea is this:

1. You write your code
2. You create your OpenShift account and allocate some "Gear" (or "Dyno" or whatever...) for your application
3. You commit your source code (`/src`) and the files that are necessary for the build (`pom.xml`), and use git to push it to the repository OpenShift gave you.
4. OpenShift then uses your `pom.xml` *and builds all the WAR-files on it's own*
5. Then you can use your `rhc` client tool to start your application, if that's not done automatically.

Some of these steps can be changed.

If you really have to, you can indeed compile your own Tomcat8, the tutorial you linked tells you how (more or less. The dude who did it obviously knew what he was doing there, so he might have skipped some details that seemed trivial to him).

Furthermore, if you really want, you can deploy pre-packaged WAR-files, by deliberately removing all the stuff that is necessary to build you app (removing pom.xml and all the /src), and instead adding the packaged application to your `git` repo, and then pushing it all to OpenShift. Then it will skip the build step, and just run what you gave it. OpenShift seems to provide some information about this deployment strategy: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740. Please read the documentation and make sure you understand what you want to do. For example, filter-branching your git repo and removing all source files you have ever written is *not* a good idea, even if you don't need these files on OpenShift.

Currently, I don't see anything of the standard tomcat directory structure in the tree that you show. Instead, there seem to be just some basic ruby-scripts or some other default-demo-app-stuff... That's why it's called "do it yourself". If you don't want this, take a standard Tomcat7 app.

Comment: Well *some* reading is certainly unavoidable if one is trying to deploy tomcat webapps to a cloud platform. Did it answer your question, or did it at least provide enough overview so that you are no longer "stuck"? Should I add something to make it an `accept`able answer?